# Switch statements for text types from a map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Right now I am working on a website where I get text from CMS and I need to recognise if it's a h3, h2, paragraph etc. So I have a switch statement, but for some reason it just shows [object Object] on my page. I console logged `<h2>{text.text}</h2>` and it shows an object so I think it has to do something with that. Does someone know how I need to do this?

What the expected results needs to be, that if the text.type is paragraph for example, it shows the text as a

{text}

When I console log `text.text` it just shows the string of text.

```
import { TextBlock } from './ArticleBodyText.styles';

export const ArticleBodyText = ({ text }) => {
  const TextBlocks = () => {
    switch (true) {
      case text.type === 'paragraph':
        return <TextBlock dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: <p>{text.text}</p> }} />;
      case text.type === 'heading3':
        return <TextBlock dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: <h3>{text.text}</h3> }} />;
      case text.type === 'heading2':
        return <TextBlock dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: <h2>{text.text}</h2> }} />;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };
  return <div>{TextBlocks()}</div>;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent from writing six different cases for six different headings, use regex to get the number of the heading and set that in the innerHTML.

**Just like this**

```
case text.type.includes('heading'): {
        const matches = text.type.match(/\d+/g);
        const heading = `h${matches[0]}`;
        return (
          <TextBlock
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: `<${heading}>text.text}</${heading}>`,
            }}
          />
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I suggest you use `if` instead of `switch`. Or not, you can use `switch` with `text.type`
2. The `TextBlocks` should return something in the end.

```
import { TextBlock } from './ArticleBodyText.styles';

export const ArticleBodyText = ({ text }) => {
  const TextBlocks = () => {
    switch (text.type) {
      case 'paragraph':
        return <TextBlock dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: <p>{text.text}</p> }} />;
      case 'heading3':
        return <TextBlock dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: <h3>{text.text}</h3> }} />;
      case 'heading2':
        return <TextBlock dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: <h2>{text.text}</h2> }} />;
      default:
        return <></>;
    }
  };
  return <div>{TextBlocks()}</div>;
};
```

That code will work as your wish!

Answer (score 0):

```
import { TextBlock } from './ArticleBodyText.styles';

export const ArticleBodyText = ({ text }) => {
  const TextBlocks = () => {
    switch (text.type) {
      case 'paragraph':
        return <TextBlock dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: <p>{text.text}</p> }} />;
      case 'heading3':
        return <TextBlock dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: <h3>{text.text}</h3> }} />;
      case 'heading2':
        return <TextBlock dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: <h2>{text.text}</h2> }} />;
      default:
        return <></>;
    }
  };
  return <div>{TextBlocks()}</div>;
};
```

Comment: Good answer! But to make it perfecet, try adding always context and add extra information. You can add a small text before the code explaining why you suggest that and the difference from others' comments and point the reader to an additional doc about the usage or .type (for instance) at the end, after the code block.

Answer (score 0):

You can even use Object literal functionality and the code looks cleaner I think.

```
export const ArticleBodyText = ({ text }) => {

    const TextBlocks = {
      paragraph: (
        <TextBlock dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: <p>{text.text}</p> }} />
      ),
      heading3: (
        <TextBlock dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: <h3>{text.text}</h3> }} />
      ),
      heading2: (
        <TextBlock dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: <h2>{text.text}</h2> }} />
      ),
    };

  return <div>{TextBlocks[text] || <>Undefined text block</>}</div>;
};
```

You can just map your components to your defined text elements and render them. If nothing is found, you can even provide a default block for that. Attached is the sample sandbox.

[image: Edit affectionate-raman-i1i1l8]

Answer (score -1):

Already solved it, the right code was:

```
import { TextBlock } from './ArticleBodyText.styles';

export const ArticleBodyText = ({ text }) => {
  const TextBlocks = () => {
    switch (true) {
      case text.type === 'paragraph':
        return <TextBlock dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `<p>${text.text}</p>` }} />;
      case text.type === 'heading3':
        return <TextBlock dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `<h3>${text.text}</h3>` }} />;
      case text.type === 'heading2':
        return <TextBlock dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `<h2>${text.text}</h2>` }} />;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };
  return <div>{TextBlocks()}</div>;
};
```

Comment: Notice that you remount the TextBlock on every render, instead move it to a constant and render it.